# Extending ViewPager to disable multi-touch swipe

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I have the following class, which extends ViewPager, so that I can disable multi-touch swiping.  I want multi-touch swiping for another feature in my app.  When I do use this class, it mysteriously crashes.

```
public class SingleSwipeViewPager extends ViewPager
{
    public SingleSwipeViewPager(final Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public SingleSwipeViewPager(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev)
    {
        if (ev.getPointerCount() == 1)
        {
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The exception message is "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range", and the stack trace is...

```
01-09 21:33:12.256 25542-25542/com.example E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
01-09 21:33:12.261 25542-25542/com.example E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example, PID: 25542
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pointerIndex out of range
at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetAxisValue(Native Method)
at android.view.MotionEvent.getX(MotionEvent.java:2014)
at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompatEclair.getX(MotionEventCompatEclair.java:32)
at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat$EclairMotionEventVersionImpl.getX(MotionEventCompat.java:110)
at android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat.getX(MotionEventCompat.java:462)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2080)
at com.example.app.SingleSwipeViewPager.onTouchEvent(SingleSwipeViewPager.java:38)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8472)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2400)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2093)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2406)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2107)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2625)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1770)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2742)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2586)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8667)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4129)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3995)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3550)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3603)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3569)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3686)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3577)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3743)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3550)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3603)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3569)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3577)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3550)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5813)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5787)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5758)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5903)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(
```

Any help in dealing with extending the swipe functionality of ViewPager would be much appreciated.

Comment: Future reference: do not use pastebin for your errors. You can include the text in your posts just like the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable swipe only for **viewpager**, you can use this code

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager{

public CustomViewPager(Context context){
    super(context);
}

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: I only want to disable the multi-touch swiping, so that more than one finger will not swipe; not disable it entirely.

Comment: Change onInterceptTouchEvent() and onTouchEvent(), to return false, if "event.getPointerCount() > 1" and call the default implementation else...